# C# 10 (De)Serialize XML property value AND attributes using StringWriter, StringReader and XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, stringreader, stringwriter

How do I (de)serialize the following xml element:

```
<OtherInfo name=\"Some Name\" type=\"text\">Hello World!!!\n</OtherInfo>
```

I define the following class to take care of the attributes:

```
[Serializable]
public class OtherInfo
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public OtherInfo() { }
    public OtherInfo(string name, string type) => (Name, Type) = (name, type);
}
```

But how do I handle the property value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a new property to your class and decorate it with the `XmlText` attribute. Here a quick link to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute?view=net-6.0).

```
[Serializable]
public class OtherInfo
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public OtherInfo() { }

    public OtherInfo(string name, string type, string value) => (Name, Type, Value) = (name, type, value);
}
```